# Take next date value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (A) and another table(B) with this information:

[image]

What I am trying to do is get something like **FINAL DATA** in the image........
if the Receipt value doesn't match with the ExecutionDate+ExecutionTime in the same day ... the query should take the first next ExecutionDate+ExecutionTime

Let me explain you what I am trying to get with 2 retailers:

**COSTWH - 2017-12-26 11:15:09:000**

This one should take the value

**SellThru Refresh - 2017-12-26 23:30:00 in the table B**

because the receipt date was before the execution time ( 11:15:09:000 vs 23:30:00) so the final data should look like

**COSTWH - 2017-12-26 11:15:09:000 - 2017-12-26 23:30:00**

**for AMAZONCA - 2017-12-26 23:59:08:000** -----

the value from table B should be

**SellThru Refresh - 2017-12-27- 04:30:00**

WHY? --- because the receipt date was after the last execution on that day ('2017-12-26 23:59:08:000' VS '2017-12-26 23:30:00') so the query should take the next closest execution and in this case is '2017-12-27','04:30:00'

so the data for AMAZONCA should look like

**AMAZONCA - 2017-12-26 23:59:08:000 - 2017-12-27 04:30:00'**

---

SAMPLEDATA:

Table A

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
   Retailer    VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL 
  ,ReceiptDate DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('AMAZON','2017-12-26 07:00:12:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('MEIJER','2017-12-26 07:00:13:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMC01','2017-12-26 07:00:13:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMC01:COM','2017-12-26 07:00:13:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMSPR','2017-12-26 07:00:13:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMT:COMCA','2017-12-26 07:00:14:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMT001:COM','2017-12-26 07:00:14:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMTCAN','2017-12-26 07:00:14:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARGET','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TARSTO','2017-12-26 09:30:11:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCM','2017-12-26 11:15:09:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCN','2017-12-26 11:15:09:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCN','2017-12-26 11:15:09:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCN:COM','2017-12-26 11:15:09:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTWH','2017-12-26 11:15:09:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('AMAZONCA','2017-12-26 23:59:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('AMAZON','2017-12-26 23:59:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMSMX','2017-12-26 23:59:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMT001:COM','2017-12-26 23:59:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('BBYCAN','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('MEIJER','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SYNNEX','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('TECD01','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMC01','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMC01:COM','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMSPR','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMT:COMCA','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMT001','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMTCAN','2017-12-27 07:00:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('WMT001','2017-12-27 10:15:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCM','2017-12-27 11:15:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCN','2017-12-27 11:15:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTCN:COM','2017-12-27 11:15:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('COSTWH','2017-12-27 11:15:08:000');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('SAMSMX','2017-12-27 23:59:10:000');
```

Table B

```
CREATE TABLE TableB(
   jobname   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
  ,ExecutionDate Date NOT NULL
  ,StartTime Time NOT NULL
  ,EndTime Time NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-26','23:30:00','23:33:30');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-27','04:30:00','04:48:29');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-27','07:15:00','07:19:29');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-27','11:30:00','11:36:15');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-27','15:00:00','15:08:50');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-27','23:30:00','23:34:52');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-28','04:30:00','05:05:02');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-28','07:15:00','07:27:38');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-28','11:30:00','11:37:51');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-28','15:00:00','15:13:38');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ('SellThru Refresh','2017-12-28','23:30:00','23:33:16');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then it should be like this:

```
select distinct Retailer
     , ReceiptDate
     , (select min(CAST(ExecutionDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME))  -- first appearance
        from TableB
        where CAST(ExecutionDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) >= TableA.ReceiptDate) DataRefresh  
from TableA 
order by Retailer
     , ReceiptDate
```

And the result is like this:

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  Retailer  |       ReceiptDate       |       DataRefresh       |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| AMAZON     | 2017-12-26 07:00:12.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| AMAZON     | 2017-12-26 23:59:08.000 | 2017-12-27 04:30:00.000 |
| AMAZONCA   | 2017-12-26 23:59:08.000 | 2017-12-27 04:30:00.000 |
| BBYCAN     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| COSTCM     | 2017-12-26 11:15:09.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| COSTCM     | 2017-12-27 11:15:08.000 | 2017-12-27 11:30:00.000 |
| COSTCN     | 2017-12-26 11:15:09.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| COSTCN     | 2017-12-27 11:15:08.000 | 2017-12-27 11:30:00.000 |
| COSTCN:COM | 2017-12-26 11:15:09.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| COSTCN:COM | 2017-12-27 11:15:08.000 | 2017-12-27 11:30:00.000 |
| COSTWH     | 2017-12-26 11:15:09.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| COSTWH     | 2017-12-27 11:15:08.000 | 2017-12-27 11:30:00.000 |
| MEIJER     | 2017-12-26 07:00:13.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| MEIJER     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| SAMC01     | 2017-12-26 07:00:13.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| SAMC01     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| SAMC01:COM | 2017-12-26 07:00:13.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| SAMC01:COM | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| SAMSMX     | 2017-12-26 23:59:08.000 | 2017-12-27 04:30:00.000 |
| SAMSMX     | 2017-12-27 23:59:10.000 | 2017-12-28 04:30:00.000 |
| SAMSPR     | 2017-12-26 07:00:13.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| SAMSPR     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| SYNNEX     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| TARGET     | 2017-12-26 09:30:11.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| TARSTO     | 2017-12-26 09:30:11.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| TECD01     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| WMT:COMCA  | 2017-12-26 07:00:14.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| WMT:COMCA  | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| WMT001     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
| WMT001     | 2017-12-27 10:15:08.000 | 2017-12-27 11:30:00.000 |
| WMT001:COM | 2017-12-26 07:00:14.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| WMT001:COM | 2017-12-26 23:59:08.000 | 2017-12-27 04:30:00.000 |
| WMTCAN     | 2017-12-26 07:00:14.000 | 2017-12-26 23:30:00.000 |
| WMTCAN     | 2017-12-27 07:00:08.000 | 2017-12-27 07:15:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: the query is good but it is showing only the most recent values and I need all from table A with the datarefresh column

Comment: First one show all from TableA, you see? I posted 2 queries

Comment: yep, but it is taking the first execution in a day ... If you see the image  (FINAL DATA is what I am trying to get) the data should take the multiple ExecutionDate+StartTime in a day

Comment: it is something like ... if receiptdate < ExecutionDate+StartTime then take the row ..... else take the next ExecutionDate+StartTime value

Comment: So, it should take multiple executions in the same day? If there is no then it should take first next day?

Comment: yes, lets say we have retailer A - 3:15 pm  and B - 6:30 pm in table A .... and in  table B we have .... Day 1 - 4:00 PM and Day 1 - 6:45 PM .... the final dataset should show A - 3:15 PM  - 4:00 PM  (the receipt time was at 3 pm and the execution at 4 pm) and the next one should be B-6;30 PM - 6:45 PM ... in case that have a third value in the same day but the last execution was at 6:45 the logic should be take the first execution on the next day: C - 9:45 PM - 4:45 AM (Day 2)

Comment: Take a look at the table I provide to you, see that every execution is just after receipt date

Comment: You don't need the `distinct`